# How to prove if two matrices are orthogonally equivalent, then they have the same singular values

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

The question was, "Show that if two matrices are orthogonally equivalent, then they have the same singular values, and there are simple relationships between their singular vectors"

I tried to show like this.

Let $ =^∗ $ for some unitary $ $,

Suppose      $ =_ Σ_ _^∗   $      $ =_ Σ_ _^∗ $

$ _ Σ_ _^∗=_ Σ_ _^∗ ^∗ $

$ Σ_  = _^∗ (_ Σ_ _^∗ ^∗)_ $

$     Σ_ ^∗=(_^∗ _) Σ_ (_^∗ ^∗ _) $

Any tips to prove this ?

Comment: What are orthogonally (or whatever) *equivalent* matrices? Like similar matrices?

Comment: Orthogonal equivalence implies unitary equivalence and similarity.

Comment: @F Don't tell me what orthogonal equivalence *implies*, but what it **means** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu $ a singular value of $A$. Then there is $x \ne 0$ such that

$A^{\star}Ax= \mu x$. Let $y=Q^{\star}x$. Then $y\ne 0$ and

$ \mu x=QB^{\star}Q^{\star}QBQ^{\star}x=QB^{\star}BQ^{\star}x$ thus

$$ \mu y=B^{\star}By$$

and $\mu$ is a singular value of $B$